# How do you monitor performance of browser extensions?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

Assume that you're developing a browser extension. Is there any way to monitor the performance of that browser extension that has been installed on all those browsers?

Ie, can you somehow monitor whether the performance degrades on a new release of the extension, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to monitor the performance of your browser extension.

For **Chrome**:

You can simply view the built-in Chrome Devtools by clicking `F12`/`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` or right click and  choose `Inspect`.

From there you can:

- [Analyze Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/#javascript) - you can check the Javascript, Style, Layout and Paint and composite calculations
- [Analyzing Network Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) - to understand why a page loads slowly
- [Analyze Memory Problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) - to find memory issues that affect page performance, including memory leaks, memory bloat, and frequent garbage collections.

For **FireFox**:

Firefox has a [responsive design view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) that encourages you to stop thinking in terms of specific devices and instead explore how your design changes at common screen sizes or your own size by dragging the edges.

For **Edge**:

To emulate Windows Phones, use Microsoft Edge's [built-in emulation](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/emulation/).

Since Edge does not ship with legacy compatibility, use [IE 11's Emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255001(v=vs.85)) to simulate how your page would look in older versions of Internet Explorer.

> **Note**: Browser emulators are great for testing a site's responsiveness,
>   but they don’t emulate differences in API, CSS support, and certain
>   behaviors that you'd see on a mobile browser.

For more infos:

- [Creating One Browser Extension For All Browsers: Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Brave And Vivaldi](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/browser-extension-edge-chrome-firefox-opera-brave-vivaldi/)
- [Emulate and Test Other Browsers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/testing-other-browsers)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! Do you know if there is any way of monitoring a browser extension that are already in the wild to see performance issues as they happen?

Comment: When you already have the built-in devtools per each browser, you can easily monitor the performance of your extension.